# Gradld Build - Use Mock Objects Created by Mockito for running unit tests

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, mockito

I have a Spring Boot application that connects to an external webservice. The project is built using gradle. I am mocking the external call in my program. When I run as junit test in STS , the test is running successfully. However when I do a "gradle build", the test is failing. When I looked into the logs , I think it is failing because the test is hitting the actual service instead of return the mocked object. Is there anything that I need to do in order for my gradle build to pick the mock objects generated by mockito as part of tests?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ProxyApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ApplicationWrapperTest {

    @Mock
    private SoapClient soapClient;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationWrapper applicationWrapper;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDatesInApplication() throws Exception{
      //return mock object (webservice response) when soapClient is called
    }
```

**ApplicationWrapper Code**

```
@Component
public class ApplicationWrapper {

    @Resource(name = "factory.soapClient")
    private SoapClientFactory soapClientFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JsonUtil jsonUtil;

    @Autowired
    private DomainUtil domainUtil;

    private static final String clientId = "soapClient";

    public String execute(String request, String apiName){
        Object req = domainUtil.createRequest(request, apiName);
        Object jaxbResponse = this.soapClientFactory.getClient(clientId).marshalSendAndReceive(req); 
        Object response = domainUtil.createResponse(jaxbResponse, apiName);
        return jsonUtil.toJsonString(response) ;
    }


  }
```

Comment: Could you add your `ProxyApplication` class code? It could be possible that it is overriding your mock and due to differences in the Gradle / Eclipse classpath, it is only overriding in the Gradle case.

Comment: Hi @adamr , the ProxyApplication class is a SpringBoot Main class and it has a number of component scans present. Is there a way to ensure mock always takes the precedence during build?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are hitting the actual service because you are using beans plugged through `ProxyApplication.class`.  The problem is that you are mixing 2 test approaches: Mockito and Spring.

To avoid these you have several choices:

1. Run tests without `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class` and Spring configurations. Remove `@Autowired`. Use `MockitoJUnitRunner.class`. This will be true unit test

   ```
   @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
   public class ApplicationWrapperTest {

   @Mock
   private SoapClientFactory soapClientFactory;

   @Mock
   private SoapClient soapClient;

   @InjectMocks
   private ApplicationWrapper applicationWrapper;

   @Before
   public void init() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   @Test
   public void testDatesInApplication() throws Exception{
     when(soapClientFactory.getClient(eq("yourclientid"))).thenReturn(soapClient);
     //return mock object (webservice response) when soapClient is called
   }
   ```
2. Create spring test configuration class for your Spring configuration where `soapClient` is configured as Mock.

Comment: Hi jny , I was making a call to applicationWrapper.execute in the testDatesInApplication method. This method has 2 autowired beans which I want to be injected. I just wanted to mock the external call alone. Hence I used both the approaches. If I remove SpringJUnit4ClassRunner , I am getting an NPE as the spring bean is not injected.When I combine both the approaches , the unit test works fine in the IDE but not during gradle build.

Comment: Which bean is not injected? Are you using MockitoJUnitRunner.class?

Comment: Yes , I initially tried using MockitoJunitRunner and came across this issue. The beans are not injected when I use MockitoJunitRunner  alone. Hence I experimented with using both SpringJunit4ClassRunner and Mockito.

Comment: I would need to see more details to see why the beans are not wired. As it is defined in my example, soapClient should be injected in applicationWrapper.

Comment: I have pasted the applicationWrapper code. DomainUtil and JSONUtil are not being autowired.

Comment: As I can see from your code, you have soapClientFactory autowired, not soap client. What you need is to add a mock for soapClientFactory. I'll update the answer